# Customising book titles in references/sources

Tags: style, citations

Some book  use lower case titles while others use upper and lower case. Should I stick to  authors choice or customise upper and lower case (as per correct usage of caps in titles).
When re checking library sources I am not confident that the case they use is correct (sometimes I find it isn't).

Comment: Welcome to Writers!  Is there a particular style guide you're supposed to use, or are you free to make any decision you like here?

Answer (score 1):

You should generally always use the work's original capitalization whenever possible. It is seen as a kind of courtesy to leave the title untouched when citing it in something. Some authors capitalize words such as *is* or *it*, and this can understandably be frustrating, but since it's contained in a proper noun, you should leave it as it is.